# Unable to enable Sign In With Apple in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to activate the **Sign In With Apple** in my application but for some reason, it only works in release mode. When I enable Sign In With Apple in capabilities, it does work but it says **Sign In With Apple (release)**. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but **Sign In With Apple** is also enabled for this `bundleID` in Apple Developer Portal.

It throws an error in development mode so I'm not sure if it will work in release mode. I got this upon clicking the apple sign in button:

`authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)"`.

Comment: have you checked entitlement file is the same path for both debug and release under the build setting tab?

Comment: I just checked they seems to be different one says App/App.entitlements other says App/AppRelease.entitlements

Comment: make it the same for both. do one thing in your project you have two files delete both and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved! Based on Raja Kishan comments, I changed the App Entitlement file in debug mode and set it to the release files and now it works fine.